# How to call JSON via POST request by clicking on HTML button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

I've tried to call to POST request via Json by clicking on button from my HTML document but it's back with an error 404, Maybe the Json request it's the issue here or maybe the Jquery code, I really don't know.

The API server is exist and ready.
I just want to make some "shortcut link" to the request by Json file that send direct to the API server.
The code I've tried to use is below:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
        $jq1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $jq1(function() {
        $jq1( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
     </script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $jq2 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>

    <script>
$jq2(document).ready(function(){
$jq2("button").click(function(){
$jq2.ajax({
  url: "https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads",
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  data: "request.json",
success: function(data){ 
    console.log("success: ", data); 
},
error: function(err){ 
    console.log("error: ", err); 
},
  dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    });
 }); 
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="tabs-4">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <th><h2>POST requests - Production</h2></th>
      </tr>

    <td>
    <ul class="b">
    <button>Send POST request</button><br><br>
    </td>
    </body>
```

This is the response from the POST request (error 404):

```
Remote Address:23.253.174.91:443
Request URL:https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery11110012059795670211315_1413464815326&request.json&_=1413464815327
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic dmNpdGE6c3RhZ2luZw==
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:mp_934d895d2a43b6804e4df6f0cb54008d_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2214903ad2cbf84-02b7a455d-4748032e-1fa400-14903ad2cc01f2%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; remember_admin_token=BAhbB1sGaRVJIiIkMmEkMTAkd3lTdlAwODlJb295WTUxMHp6Um5XLgY6BkVU--9a67de09d5a72b8805f589528aca55099335e9de; __zlcmid=RHe7qTN3yuF9zc; __utma=102324637.495385716.1413102578.1413308718.1413311902.12; __utmc=102324637; __utmz=102324637.1413102578.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _vcita_session_integration=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%2FaQIbDiIlNjk0NzUwYjFlNzFiOTlhMjdmMTI3NDU3ZmQzZmJkMGJJIhx3YXJkZW4udXNlci56b25lXzEyLmtleQY7AFRbCGkCDElpESIlMjdlYjJkNjEyYmJkMmNhZGIxYWU5MGEwMWZmMTUyOGNJIhl3YXJkZW4udXNlci51c2VyLmtleQY7AFRbB1sGaQKfD0kiGXBidm9wWWpHWHlqenpKc3hKcEFvBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMUtweGVycXMzcDFXaC9rWTNMVkdXM2tGSE1QSnFleTVSV2JRYStacDl3STg9BjsARg%3D%3D--138e9dee16f3409e7b8870b0e0053888777776a4; mp_d482fd7678983cbb47786f77b1e63bbd_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%223999%22%2C%22Landing%20Page%22%3A%20%22Dashboard%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22Invite%22%3A%20%22WEB_PRO_SUB%22%2C%22Source%20Referrer%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffight.meet2know.com%2Fv%2Fzap.1234%2Fhome%22%2C%22Origin%22%3A%20%22Top%20menu%20-%20account%22%2C%22User%20Type%22%3A%20%22Individual%22%2C%22User%20Id%22%3A%203999%2C%22Full%20Name%22%3A%20%22Samuel%20L.%20Jackson%22%2C%22Industry%22%3A%20%22Financial%20Services%22%2C%22Profession%22%3A%20%22Financial%20Services%20%2F%20Bank%22%2C%22Time%20Zone%22%3A%20%22Amsterdam%22%2C%22Pivot%20Id%22%3A%203846%2C%22Locale%22%3A%20%22en%22%2C%22Plan%22%3A%20%22Ultimate%22%2C%22Business%22%3A%20%22false%22%2C%22Trial%22%3A%20%22false%22%2C%22Directory%20Name%22%3A%20%22doctors.co.il%22%2C%22__mps%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%22__mpso%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%22__mpa%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%22__mpap%22%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%22Marketing%20Channel%22%3A%20%22Wix%22%2C%22Source%20Type%22%3A%20%22Unknown%22%7D
Host:api.meet2know.com
Referer:http://idantesting.comuv.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery11110012059795670211315_1413464815326
request.json:
_:1413464815327
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 16 Oct 2014 13:07:12 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
P3P:CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.6.0
Set-Cookie:source_invite=WEBP-REG; path=/
Set-Cookie:invitation=3079; path=/
Set-Cookie:pivots=3846; path=/; expires=Mon, 16-Oct-2034 13:07:12 GMT
Status:404 Not Found
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Rack-Cache:miss
X-Request-Id:8c74b6d83cce50d70100b31491f7eeed
X-Runtime:0.065370
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

This is the error from the console log:

```
    GET https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery1111009170888806693256_1413466282769&request.json&_=1413466282770  
jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax 
jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
(index):30m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle
```

And.. This is the JSON File (request.json)

```
{
  "authorization": "Token",
  "token": "15eed06....",
  "business_id": "87cf...",
  "identifier_type": "email",
  "email": "idan.1212@hotmail.com",
  "request_title": "idantesting",
  "first_name": "demo",
  "last_name": "testing",
  "source": "QA_Sendbox",
  "message": "body msg"
}
```

Comment: You have not closed the `.ready` and `.click` functions, nor the actual `script`tag. Is this maybe just a typo?

Comment: There is also a TD as a child of table which is invalid HTML and might not work properly.

Comment: You are right, but It's not the issue on this case, because it's receive error from the server @MyHeadHurts (see attachment: http://i59.tinypic.com/25qg9k5.jpg)

Comment: What does the console error say?

Comment: Consol log: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://idantesting.comuv.com' is therefore not allowed access.  @Spokey

Comment: @IdanQA try with dataType: 'jsonp'. That URL seems to also need authentification

Comment: Thanks @Spokey. Now it sent it! but is receive an error of 404 not found :/

Remote Address:23.253.174.91:443
Request URL:https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery11110012059795670211315_1413464815326&request.json&_=1413464815327
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic dmNpdGE6c3RhZ2luZw===1

Comment: Nobody can read that, please post it in your question. And like I said, that URL needs auth. You have to send a username and password to access the page

Comment: Yeah, I did it..Now I'm stuck in something else.. I think that something wrong with my Json request.. :/
@Spokey

Comment: You are not sending any username or password with your request

Comment: @Spokey It's present authentication dialog during the request sending and I've insert the user/pass there.
Is it not good enough? :/

Comment: This is the error from the console log:
GET https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery11110770312482258305_1413465698548&request.json&_=1413465698549  jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) (index):30m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But It doesnt matter,
I receive an error as response :/ GET https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery11110770312482258305_1413465698548&request.json&_=1413465698549 jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) (index):30m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle

Comment: Nope, you have to send the PW and username with the request. Adding `username: 'myusername'` and `password: 'mypw'` in `$.ajax({})`- You can make a form where you need to input those and them send them with the request

Comment: @Spokey Thanks, I did it but it still the same :/

console log:    
GET https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?callback=jQuery11110009230152936652303_1413465975986&request.json&_=1413465975987  jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) (index):30m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle

Comment: Type should be 'GET', or just remove it

Comment: @Spokey Thanks again, but still the same error (404 not found) :/

Comment: if you go to that URL and log in, do you see 404? Also this should be a comment not an asnwer

Comment: @Spokey I can send the request as properly by the POSTMAN
(see attached file: http://i57.tinypic.com/ngy3xu.jpg)

Comment: Yes but what about if you yourself go to the page. I see you are sending a token but I see no token that you send with jquery. Are you sure data should be request.json ?

Comment: Yes. It's should be with the JSON file of "request.json" I can add this file to here if you want to valid the file.
When I go by myself to this page it show this page isn't exist but I can send the POST request to this page properly by the POSTMAN / SoapUI @Spokey

Comment: If it shows that it doesn't exist then it doesn't exit. Look at the postman URL in the header in the network tab. Try to delete the data and send it. Visit the page while changing the URL until you find the page. Can't help you further than this since I can't see the page. The problem is the data you are sending is not the right one. PS we should start a chat instead of comments :p

Comment: I don't know how to open a chat here, It's my first post.. :/
Anyway, I added the JSON content to my post. please your help.. @Spokey

Comment: Oh never mind you need 20 rep to use the chatroom. I still am not sure about the data. If you add `request.json` the resulting URL will look like https://api.meet2know.com/v1/leads?request.json. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, the json file is exist on another server.
I want to use this json file that exist in my server to POST request to the api server (api.mee2know.com...) @Spokey

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a handler for the success event instead of the `"success"` string, which does nothing, so you know when it does well...
Like this:

```
success: function(data){ 
    console.log("success: ", data); 
},
```

also, you might like to add an event listener for error as well.

```
error: function(err){ 
    console.log("error: ", err); 
},
```